# Send request from Web front-end to C++ backend

Tags: php, c++, node.js, server, pusher

My system is web-based crypto trading platform.

My front-end is Php/NodeJS, which allows user to place a stock order (a http form request)

A C++ written backend is written to send API calls to different exchanges.

Question, how to send the front-end form request to my back-end. I thought about two options but none are optimal
1) the C++ backend can also serve as a server to listen any POST message through TCP connection, then pass the messages to the trading engine. For exmaple, using socket.
2) UI send JSON messages to pusher(pusher.com), then a C++ pusher client listen to the channel to grab the messages and pass to the trading engine thread/process. Any reply needs a second channel to be sent as JSON message back to the frontend

For option 1), I am not comfortable make a C++ server as most times we use Java or Node based server

Any advice on those two options or other alternatives are welcome

Thanks.

Comment: You can use crow library to make server using c++. It is fast, easy and very much same as express when it comes to syntax. Check it out here : https://github.com/ipkn/crow

Comment: Or You can use node.js C++ Add-on to integrate C++ into Node.js (More difficult than building a server using crow)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply coder3101. will definitely check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending whole weekend researching and testing the various options, I have come up to the following options:
build a nodeJS server, then let NodeJS to communicate with C++ process. https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html